# Oracle moving average

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (date, payload) which contains data for around 10 years and I want to calculate the moving average (MA) for displaying the trend of the payload based on 14 days (2 weeks) and 90 days (12 weeks) intervals

I've written this query but it gets me wrong values

```
SELECT x.*,
  ABS (LTMA-STMA) DIFFERECNE
FROM
  (SELECT SDATE,
    PAYLOAD,
    AVG(PAYLOAD) OVER (ORDER BY W ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) STMA,
    AVG(PAYLOAD) OVER (ORDER BY W ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) LTMA
  FROM
(SELECT b.*,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR( X.SDATE, 'W')) W
FROM
  (SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(a.SDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') SDATE,
    SUM(a.PAYLOAD) PAYLOAD
  FROM TABLE_PAYLOAD a
  WHERE a.SDATE  > sysdate - 3 * 365      
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(a.SDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  ORDER BY TO_CHAR(a.SDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  ) b    )
 ORDER BY SDATE
 ) x;
```

Actually I know what `MA` is, but I don't understand how Oracle works!

I can calculate `MA` in Excel but I need to do this in database level, could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Order your final output by the same key as used in Windowing clause (Column W), then your result should get more clear.

Comment: I think your calculation of 'W' week number is not correct. W gives Week of month (1-5) where week 1 starts on the first day of the month and ends on the seventh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand what is the point of using `TO_CHAR(SDATE, 'W')` ? According to the doc this is supposed to give you the week number in the month...

Anyway I tried to simplify the query, hoping it still fit your needs:

```
SELECT x.*, ABS (LTMA-STMA) DIFFERENCE
FROM
(
  SELECT SDATE, PAYLOAD,
         AVG(PAYLOAD) OVER (ORDER BY SDATE rows BETWEEN 14 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) STMA,
         AVG(PAYLOAD) OVER (ORDER BY SDATE rows BETWEEN 90 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) LTMA
  FROM
  (
    SELECT a.SDATE, SUM(a.PAYLOAD) PAYLOAD
    FROM TABLE_PAYLOAD a
    WHERE a.SDATE  > sysdate - 3 * 365      
    GROUP BY a.SDATE
  )
) x
ORDER BY SDATE;
```

PS: I don't see the point either in doing `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(a.SDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')`, this is equivalent to `a.SDATE`...

Comment: I am getting this error *** ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis" *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 5 Column: 44 ***

Comment: Oh, sory, I used an `ORDER BY` in my inner query... I changed the query, can you please retry ?

Comment: the `to_char(a.sdate, ...)` should probably get rid of the time part that is stored in the date. using `trunc(a.sdate)` achieves the same thing and would make this more obvious I think.