# How to compare two SELECT subqueries by using the BETWEEN operator?

Tags: sql, select, subquery, between, oracle12c

I'm working with Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition.

The table looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL2L6.jpg

The table shows the stock price of different stocks with their distinct ID (WKN), their starting price (Start), their maximum price (Hoch), their low price (Tief) and their closing price (Schluss) per day by date (Datum). I now want to compute a 90-day line directly in SQL. It's calculated by determining the arithmetic mean of the closing price over the past 90 days for every day within the 90 days.

I tried to calculate this with the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUM(SCHLUSSPREIS) / 90 AS TAGESLINIE FROM KURS WHERE DATUM BETWEEN
  (SELECT DATUM FROM KURS WHERE WKN = 2 AND DATUM BETWEEN
    (SELECT MAX(DATUM) - 179 FROM KURS) AND
    (SELECT MAX(DATUM) - 90 FROM KURS) ORDER BY DATUM ASC)
  AND (SELECT DATUM FROM KURS WHERE WKN = 2 AND DATUM BETWEEN
   (SELECT MAX(DATUM) - 89 FROM KURS) AND
   (SELECT MAX(DATUM) FROM KURS) ORDER BY DATUM ASC)
;
```

To give you a much better overview of this confusing statement, I created the following scheme: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjYXf.jpg

Both, the first subquery...

```
(SELECT DATUM FROM KURS WHERE WKN = 2 AND DATUM BETWEEN
  (SELECT MAX(DATUM) - 179 FROM KURS) AND
  (SELECT MAX(DATUM) - 90 FROM KURS) ORDER BY DATUM ASC)
```

... and the second subquery...

```
(SELECT DATUM FROM KURS WHERE WKN = 2 AND DATUM BETWEEN
  (SELECT MAX(DATUM) - 89 FROM KURS) AND
  (SELECT MAX(DATUM) FROM KURS) ORDER BY DATUM ASC)
```

... do return a list of the same amount of dates (90).

The first date in the list of the first subquery belongs to the first date in the list of the second subquery, the second date in the list of the first subquery belongs to the second date in the list of the second subquery, etc. (comp. scheme obove). I now want my SQL statement to sum up all closing prices between each of these periods (from first date (list 1) to first date (list 2), etc.) and divide it by 90 to get the arithmetic mean, until both lists are empty.

However, if I run this, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

or

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01427: single row subquery returns more than one row
```

Any idea how to do something like this directly in SQL?

Any help is appreciated- Thank you! :-)

Comment: Research what a `JOIN` is: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm

Comment: You could write a SQL function to compute the 90 day average. It accepts a WKN and end date as parameters, and returns the average. Test this separate from the main query and get it working. Then you call this function from your main SQL select.

Comment: I have to do this for university and we aren't allowed to use user defined SQL functions. I'll try to solve it with a join and the coalesce() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUM` is not the only aggregate function available in SQL.
Here you might want to use `AVG` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
     DATUM,
     AVG(SCHLUSSPREIS) OVER (ORDER BY DATUM rows BETWEEN 89 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS TAGESLINIE
  FROM KURS
  WHERE WKN = 2
  ORDER BY DATUM DESC
) Moving_Average
WHERE ROWNUM <= 90;
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip but that's actually not my problem. The problem is that I have two subqueries between a BETWEEN statement, both retuning a list of dates like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XjYXf.jpg). I now want that the BETWEEN statement to compare each date from the first list with the date from the second list that has the same position on the order. But because of the error message (_single row subquery returns more than one row_), I think this is not possible with BETWEEN. So how to do something like this without user defined SQL functions?

Comment: Does that: [Oracle moving average](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22166986/5690722) ring a bell?

Comment: I admit, my problem is a little confusing. I want SQL to calculate a 90-day line from a certian stock, starting from the highest current available date of this stock (that's why i use MAX(DATUM)). But in order to do this you have to determine the arithmetic mean of the closing price over the past 90 days for every day within the 90 days. So in the end you should receive 90 different arithmetic means. Let's say MAX(DATUM) is the 31-DEC-15. Then, the first arithmetic mean would be calculated from all closing prices between MAX(DATUM) - 89 and MAX(DATUM). [Continued on next comment]

Comment: The second arithmetic mean from all closing prices between MAX(DATUM) - 90 and MAX(DATUM) - 1. The third from all closing prices between MAX(DATUM) - 91 days and MAX(DATUM) - 2 etc. until this is done for all 90 days.

Comment: Thank you! There are just two small mistakes: First, in this specific case, AVG is not a GROUP BY expression, so just remove it. Second, the statement will return the wrong result because you wrote 90 instead of 89 in the OVER clause. Therefore, SQL uses 91 values for the calculation, rather than the 90. Everything else is fine. Ones again a big thank you!